# Calculate histogram from a set of data using the standard library or the boost library

Tags: c++

My problem is pretty simple. I have an array of floats with random values. And I would like to find the number of occurences of values in the array.

For example.

```
float data[] = {1.1,1.1,1.1,
              2.1,2.1,2.1,
              3.1,3.1,3.1,
              4.1,4.1,4.1,
              5.1,5.1,5.1,
              1.5,1.5,1.5,
              3.2,3.2,3.2};
```

Is there some kind of range histogram function in the standard library or the boost library that will return me the number of occurences of the values. In the above example,

```
0-1 -> 0 times
1-2 -> 6 times
2-3 -> 3 times
3-4 -> 6 times
4-5 -> 3 times
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no direct histogram function in the stdlib. You can use a map to track counts as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820275/count-how-many-times-elements-in-an-array-are-repeated)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this an interview question?

Comment: @Ron no, i am trying to find the number of occurences of displacement vector in a dense optical  flow algorithm like faerneback.

Comment: @infoclogged It's all Greek to me but thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a `std::map` that readily does what you want:

```
std::vector<double> data = {1.1,1.1,1.1,
              2.1,2.1,2.1,
              3.1,3.1,3.1,
              4.1,4.1,4.1,
              5.1,5.1,5.1,
              1.5,1.5,1.5,
              3.2,3.2,3.2};

std::map<int,int> histogram;

for (const auto& e : data) ++histogram[e];

for (const auto& x : histogram) std::cout << x.first << " " << x.second <<"\n";
```

prints:

```
1 6
2 3
3 6
4 3
5 3
```

I allowed myself to use a `vector` instead of the c-array. A map stores key-value pairs, its `operator[]` returns a reference to the value for the given key (and default constructs it if there is none yet).

Comment: What if I need the counts between `{[0.0,1.5] , [1.5,3.0] , [3.0,4.5] , [4.5,6.0]}`?

Comment: @yellow01 thats what the question is about. For arbitrary intervals you need a bit more. Store the interval start points in a vector (you dont need both, start and end point, when there are no holes) then for each data point determine in which interval it falls (eg via `std::upper_bound`) and then use a map to count

Answer (score 1):

To complement the accepted answer, it is also possible to calculate the histogram for arbitrary intervals as long as you sort your data array.

```
std::vector<double> data = {1.1,1.1,1.1,
                            2.1,2.1,2.1,
                            3.1,3.1,3.1,
                            4.1,4.1,4.1,
                            5.1,5.1,5.1,
                            1.5,1.5,1.5,
                            3.2,3.2,3.2};

std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());

std::map<double, int> histogram;

double bin = 0; //Choose your starting bin
const double bin_width = 1.5; //Choose your bin interval
for (const auto& e : data)
{
    e >= bin + bin_width ? bin += bin_width : false;
    ++histogram[bin];
}

for (const auto& x : histogram) 
{
    std::printf("[%.2f,%.2f[ : %d\n", x.first, x.first + bin_width, x.second);
}
```

prints:

```
[0.00,1.50[ : 3
[1.50,3.00[ : 6
[3.00,4.50[ : 9
[4.50,6.00[ : 3
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) . And this posible solution:

```
int count(std::vector<float> &data, const float lower, const float upper) {
    return std::count_if(data.begin(), data.end(),[&lower, &upper](float i){return i>lower && i<upper;});
}
```

Comment: using this OP would have to traverse the input for each of the intervals