# Given n positive integer numbers.Print how many numbers occurs at least 2 times in this array on C++

Tags: c++

Input:
4
1 2 2 3
Output:
1

Hello guys! There is one problem...I planned to make this through a map, but...

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    map<int,int> m;
    map<int,int> :: iterator it = m.begin();
    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++){
        cin >> arr[i];
        it = m.find(arr[i]);
        if(*it == m.size());
    }
    return 0;
}`
```

ProblemC.cpp:15:26: note:   'std::pair<const int, int>' is not derived from 'const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>'
if(*it == m.size());
^

I don't even know how to properly solve this, please help me
[Here is a photo with more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPc1N.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820275/count-how-many-times-elements-in-an-array-are-repeated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that in `if` statement you want to check if `find` algorithm returned end of map. Better way to do it is to try to insert value into map and check operation return value.
You should change it to:

```
if (!m.insert({arr[i], 1}).second)
{
    counter++;
}
```